# Don't understand bash parameter declaration

Tags: linux, command

I have a problem with reading this parameter below:

1. I don't understand the purpose of using this `$(basename "$0")` where is it come from.
2. `${BINARY%/*}` seems it try to get the path of the directory but what exactly why just need to like this.

```
DIR_NAME=$(dirname "$0")
FILE_NAME=$(basename "$0")
BINARY=`readlink ${ROOT_DIR}/${DIR_NAME}/${FILE_NAME} -f`
BIN_PATH=${BINARY%/*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$0` is the pathname of the script being run. So `$(dirname "$0")` returns the directory of the script, and `$(basename "$0")` is the filename.
2. `${BINARY%/*}` is explained in [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> `${parameter%word}`
>   `${parameter%%word}`
>   The `word` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of `parameter`, then the result of the expansion is the value of `parameter` with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted.

So this finds the trailing portion of `$BINARY` that matches `/*` and removes it, which returns the directory portion. It's equivalent to `$(dirname "$BINARY")`